# apache ant <javadoc>: how to disable timestamp

Tags: ant, javadoc

As I know, javadoc command line(/usr/bin/javadoc) has an option which named "-notimestamp" to remove the timestamp in the final html file.

How to do the same thing in Apache Ant Javadoc Task?

```
<javadoc
    destdir="${docs.lib}"
    author="false"
    version="false"
    use="true"
    ...
</javadoc>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html), it supports nested `arg` elements. Try something like:

```
<javadoc
    destdir="${docs.lib}"
    author="false"
    version="false"
    use="true"
    ...>
    <arg value="-notimestamp"/>
</javadoc>
```

There is also an `additionalparam` attribute. Try:

```
<javadoc
    destdir="${docs.lib}"
    author="false"
    version="false"
    use="true"
    additionalparam="-notimestamp"
    ...
</javadoc>
```